# Magento 2 Image Cache Files are not Updating in Product Catalog

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache, catalog, media-images

I'm currently experiencing an intermittent issue with my product images in my installation of Magento 2.3.2.

Essentially I upload a new image to replace an existing image, the image updates in the actual product page but the catalog image is still using the original cache file. I have set the new image as "main", "small" and "thumbnail".

I've used the developer tools and while the  tag in the product page looks like this:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/9f47024c2e279a58a1d0480c74316c74/n/e/new-image.jpg" alt="New Image" aria-labelledby="labelledby1566993720460" class="fotorama__img magnify-opaque magnify-opaque" aria-hidden="false" id="magnifier-item-0">
```

The image in the catalog remains as follows:

```
<img class="product-image-photo" src="https://www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/04520e77c5e90290b61ecc3bb802e104/o/r/original-image.jpg" max-width="208" max-height="260" alt="Original Image">
```

I have tried flushing the caches and re-indexing but the cached catalog image has not updated.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try hard refresh in your browser?

Comment: Yes, several times over multiple days.